# Change the function of caps lock to insert underscores when the spacebar is hit

Tags: caps-lock

Is there a way I can change the function of my caps lock key so that when it's on it inserts_underscores_instead_of_spaces_when_i_hit_the_spacebar?

It's fine if it just works in Textmate but would be handy in other apps.

Comment: PCKeyboardHack (from the makers of KeyRemap4Macbook) can change the caps lock key to any other modifier key, if that's any use.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=Ukelele).  I tried to do this myself but got distracted and then gave up.  The documentation isn't exactly stellar.

**Note**:  Ukelele is just a GUI to simplify the process of editing the layouts manually as they are large XML files with slightly ambiguous element names.